# Using bootstrap sass as a reference but without compiling to css (gulp-sass)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, gulp, gulp-sass

I have a module in a website that is loading as an embedded feature. The website itself has bootstrap in CSS so I don't need to re-compile it all into the module but i want to use mixins and extends in the module itself.

I can just bower install bootstrap but that means to import the whole thing into the app.

Not sure if i'm doing it correctly but is there a way to reference bootstrap without compiling it into the css of the module and without using @import?